# converting number to date in Sql Server

Tags: datetime, sql-server-2012

Why does the following statement fail in Sql Server 2012:

```
select CONVERT(datetime, '42083.439259259', 120)
from Table1
```

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.
>   If I copy and paste this number in Excel, then format it as date I get: `March 20, 2015`

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quote marks around the value,

```
select CONVERT(datetime, 42083.439259259, 120)
from Table1
```

The quotes cause SQL Server to try interpreting the value as a string against the local date format, which then gives you the error you're seeing. Converting the raw number should succeed.